# How do lightweight nodes and SPV wallets calculate balances?

Tags: wallet, nodes, balance, spv

Can they do it? Or they "talk" to a full node for that purpose and are used only for mining purposes?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: See BIP37: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0037.mediawiki SPV nodes receive transactions from full nodes that match a filter pattern.

Comment: And how do they calculate balances? I read what you posted and I can't understand a word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an SPV client?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/what-is-an-spv-client). See [How is a wallet's balance computed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22997/how-is-a-wallets-balance-computed). Answers to your other questions are: Yes, Yes, No.